# Laravel: Trouble with uploading files on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, temp

I've trouble getting the file upload working with Laravel on my Windows 7 system. There is no issue with uploading the files but when I see the destination directory the uploaded file is not present.

After searching in Google and forums I found that there may be a problem with the 'Temp' directory.

The output of `dd(sys_get_temp_dir())` is `C:\Users\RAGHAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp`.

However there is no directory called `RAGHAV~1`(I've enabled to see the hidden folders). In `php.ini` the `upload_tmp_dir` is set to `C:\xampp\tmp`.

Is there any conflict between these settings? Can you please help me to get the file upload working?

The code in the controller that process the uploaded files:

```php
$validator = $this->brandValidator($request->all());

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $this->throwValidationException(
        $request, $validator
    );
}

$image_directory = public_path() . '/Uploads/Products/';

$result = $request->file('image')->move($image_directory);

$brand_name = $request->input('brand_name');
$image = $image_directory . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

$id = Brand::create([
    'brand_name' => $brand_name,
    'image' => $image,
]);
```

Comment: The filenames with `~1` are windows long-filenames, shortened to short-filenames. There's probably a folder in `C:\Users\` starting with `Raghav..` - most likely your home directory.

Comment: Yeah there is a folder - Raghavendra. so what may be the reason for file uploading not to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the path for the file. Simply replace this

```
$image_directory = public_path() . '/Uploads/Products/';

$result = $request->file('image')->move($image_directory);
```

with this

```
$file = $request->file('image');

$filename =  $file->getClientOriginalName().'.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$file->move(public_path('Uploads/Products/'), $filename);
```

Comment: not working. Getting this issue: The file "bmw.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

Comment: $file->getClientOriginalExtension() is not required. $file->getClientOriginalName() will have the extension.

Comment: yes. I've set APP_DEBUG true. SO I can see the error message in the browser. It throws me this error: The file "bmw.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.